# Foreach sets to null all variables DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, symfony

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $xmlItem = $xml->createElement("item");
    /** @var \DOMElement $xmlItem */
    $item = $xml->appendChild($xmlItem);
    $item->setAttribute("item-id:2", "abcd");
    $temp = $item->attributes;

    foreach ($temp as $attributeName => $attrValue) {
        $someValue = 2;
        $h = $attributeName;
        $theCurrent = $xmlItem->getAttribute($attributeName);
    }
```

Then I go to first row inside foreach all variables sets to null e.c. (    $item = null, $temp = null    ), and script stopped with the error:
Warning: AdLabs\PricegeneratorBundle\PriceGenerators\Generators\Google\Facade::run(): Not yet implemented in /home/egor/PhpstormProjects/priceGenerator/src/src/AdLabs/PricegeneratorBundle/PriceGenerators/Generators/Google/Facade.php line 36
line 36  that:    $someValue = 2;
please help me, what am I doing wrong?